# Pagination by issue in biblatex-apa

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

Another `biblatex-apa` question here. It seems it has not been asked before. The APA 6th edition prescribes that when formatting journals (and other periodical references), the issue number is included (in parenthesis) after the volume number when the journal is paginated by issue. Otherwise (if the journal is continuously paginated), it is not included (see p. 198 of the 6th edition of the APA Publication Manual).

It seems that, by default, `version 6.0` of `biblatex-apa` formats a journal following the continuous pagination format. How can I specify that a particular entry is paginated by issue, and, hence, the issue number should be printed?

`bibliography.bib`:

```
@article{myers,
author = {Scott W. Myers and Michael Ballweg and John L. Wedberg},
title = {Assessing the impact of {European} corn borer on corn grown for silage},
url = {http://www.uwex.edu/ces/crops/uwforage/ECB.htm},
urldate = {2013-07-09},
journaltitle = {Focus on Forage},
volume = {3},
issue = {4},
organization = {University of Wisconsin Wisconsin Team Forage},
keywords = {jared},
}
```

`sample.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `number` field for issue number. From the BibLaTeX manual:

> Quarterly journals are typically identified by a designation such as
>   ‘Spring’ or ‘Summer’ which should be given in the issue field.

So your `bibliography.bib` file will look like this:

```
@article{myers,
author = {Scott W. Myers and Michael Ballweg and John L. Wedberg},
title = {Assessing the impact of {European} corn borer on corn grown for silage},
url = {http://www.uwex.edu/ces/crops/uwforage/ECB.htm},
urldate = {2013-07-09},
journaltitle = {Focus on Forage},
volume = {3},
number = {4},
organization = {University of Wisconsin Wisconsin Team Forage},
keywords = {jared},
}
```

Making that change, I get the following output:

[image: PDF of references]

Comment: That simple? Thanks. I appreciate your time looking at this, man.

Comment: No worries. I was already working up a complex workaround using per-entry options when I realized I wouldn't get a chance to implement it. Maybe next time, Gadget.